# css ul li nested menu with a padding. How on hoover retain width of the menu?

Tags: css

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/v8yhk7Lr/

html

```
<div class="navig_div" id="mainnavig_div" >
<ul class="mnav-ul">

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#">Option One</a>
<ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
<li><a href="#">Option One 1</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Option One 1 longer</a> </li>
</ul>
</li>   

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#gg">Option Two long text</a>
<ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
<li><a href="#">Option Two 1</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Option Two 1 longer</a> </li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#">Option Three</a>
<ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
<li><a href="#">Option Three 1</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Option Three 1 longer</a> </li>
</ul>
</li>   

</ul>

</div>
```

css

```
.mnav-ul-li { float: left; display: block;   }
.mnav-ul-li a { display:inline-block; padding:10px 25px; }
.mnav-ul-ul { display: none; }
.mnav-ul-li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

Mouse over on `Option One`, see nested menu. But `Option Two long text` and `Option Three` moves to right. I want `Option Two long text` and `Option Three` remain at the same place (or `Option One` have the same width that was before mouse over).

Can set width like `.mnav-ul-li { float: left; display: block; width:150px;  }` (example here http://jsfiddle.net/v8yhk7Lr/1/) but in such case the longer text is in 2 lines and one item may be short text, another long text, so space between navigation items would be different. With padding space would be the same between all items).

How to retain width on hover (on hover keep the same width that was before hover)?

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/oo2vxf2o/?

Comment: Yes. `position: absolute;` necessary for hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.mnav-ul-li:hover > ul - add `position: absolute;`

```css
.mnav-ul-li { float: left; display: block;  position: relative; }
.mnav-ul-li a { display:inline-block; padding:10px 25px; }

.mnav-ul-ul { display: none; }

.mnav-ul-li:hover > ul { display: block; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="navig_div" id="mainnavig_div" >
<ul class="mnav-ul">

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#">Option One</a>
 <ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
 <li><a href="#">Option One 1</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#">Option One 1 longer</a> </li>
 </ul>
</li> 

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#gg">Option Two long text</a>
 <ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
 <li><a href="#">Option Two 1</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#">Option Two 1 longer</a> </li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#">Option Three</a>
 <ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
 <li><a href="#">Option Three 1</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#">Option Three 1 longer</a> </li>
 </ul>
</li> 

</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add position absolute to the ul

```
.mnav-ul-li:hover > ul { 
  display: block; 
  position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8yhk7Lr/3/